# How to fix a file that's read-only despite showing correct permissions

Tags: snow-leopard, permission

A file copied from a NTFS share has become read-only, other files in the same folder are OK.

Finder's Info says in the Sharing & Permissions:

```
You can only read 
Name        Privilege 
myname (Me) Read & Write 
admin       Read only 
everyone    Read only
```

ls -l@

```
total 142040
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myname admin  5388424 Sep 17  1998 Bad File
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myname admin  3534780 Feb  3 21:36 Good File
```

How to undo? chown/chmod didn't do anything...

Comment: What type of file is it?  How do you know it is read-only?

Comment: I try to edit it, or change its properties/permissions in the Finder, and it doesn't let me. In addition, "You can only read" in Finder's Info is a hint as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ls -lO` to see if any file flags are set.  If it's locked (uchg flag), you can unlock it in either the Finder's Get Info window, or with `chflags nouchg "Bad File"`.  If some other flag is set, use `chflags no<whatever> "Bad File"` to clear it.

EDIT: The `-O` flag to la adds another column between the group and size of the files, listing file flags (if any).  Note that flags are entirely separate from extended attributes (what `-@` displays).  Here's an example:

```
$ touch "Normal File" "Locked File" "Invisible, Append-only File"
$ chflags uchg "Locked File"
$ chflags uappnd,hidden "Invisible, Append-only File"
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--@ 1 gordon  wheel  0 Feb  4 07:24 Invisible, Append-only File
-rw-r--r--  1 gordon  wheel  0 Feb  4 07:24 Locked File
-rw-r--r--  1 gordon  wheel  0 Feb  4 07:24 Normal File
$ ls -lO
total 0
-rw-r--r--@ 1 gordon  wheel  uappnd,hidden 0 Feb  4 07:24 Invisible, Append-only File
-rw-r--r--  1 gordon  wheel  uchg          0 Feb  4 07:24 Locked File
-rw-r--r--  1 gordon  wheel  -             0 Feb  4 07:24 Normal File
```

The uchg flag is what gets set if you check the "Locked" box in a file's Get Info window.  BTW, the "hidden" flag only affects the Finder -- the only way to hide files from the command line is to put a . at the front of the filename.

Comment: Dunno if that's going to fix his problem but good answer nonetheless +1

Comment: The file was indeed locked. Could you please expand on how to identify the uchg flag in the ls output?

Answer (score 1):

Another method of unlocking said file would be in Finder itself.  Under the General expansion of Get Info.  This toggles the uchg flag.

[image: Get Info Box]